# stdio inclusion in a header file

Tags: c, include, header-files, stdio

I'm not totally sure but this looks wrong:

I have a header file named **fraction.h** in which I store a fraction structure and the methods to handle it, one method is used to write a fraction in a file and in the signature of this function one argument is a *FILE* pointer.

*fraction.h:*

```
...
const Fraction * fraction_fwrite(const Fraction * f, FILE * file);
...
```

*fraction.c:*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "fraction.h"
...
```

Now when I try to compile a program that uses a fraction, I get an error,

here is what I have in my *Makefile*:

```
program_test: fraction.o program_test.o
```

and I include **fraction.h** in **program_test.c** of course.
but I keep getting this error :

**fraction.h:34:54: error: unknown type name 'FILE'**

someone could explain the different steps through which the compiler includes files ?
because `<stdio.h>` is in **fraction.c** so why does it strike this unfound-type error ?

should I include `<stdio.h>` in **fraction.h** ? which looks not really appropriate from my measly experience.

Comment: You must include `<stdio.h>` in program_test.c as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you compile `program_test`, the compiler isn't looking at the other .c files, only the files you `#include` in the file you actually compile.

So, you either have to `#include <stdio.h>` in the test program, just like in `fraction.c`, or include it in the header file.

Even though the C standard says that the standard library files will not include each other, there is nothing saying that user defined files cannot do that. In fact it is usually much easier to use them if they do.

Comment: thanks that is clear, could you advice any links that explain thoroughly how an executable is built from a set of source files ? not that I didn't get your answer (i did) but regarding your stackoverflow credits i bet you have good place to recommend.

Comment: Maybe this one? [How does inclusion of header file happen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/705676/how-does-inclusion-of-header-file-happen) Or this [Included file from header/source file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603337/included-file-from-header-source-file)

Answer (score 1):

When the preprocessor processes a file, then it will copy the content of an included file into the file that is preprocessed. The reason why you don't get that error in `fraction.c` is that the content of `stdio.h` is included before `fraction.h` is included.

So the preprocessed file `fragments.c` looks like this:

```
    stdio.h contents
    fragment.h contents
    fragment.c contents
```

Notice that the `FILE` definition will be included through `stdio.h` before it is referenced in `fragment.h`.

You should include `stdio.h` in fraction.h to get rid of this error.

Answer (score 0):

Include stdio.h in program_test.c. If you dont include stdio.h in program_test.c (which includes fraction.h), the compiler doesn't know the definition of FILE used by fraction.h, and generates error.

And, you really should include stdio.h in fraction.h